# Deploy a process with multitenancy support using Activiti Explorer

Tags: workflow, activiti, multi-tenant

Since Activiti 5.15 added multitenancy support, i have used the Activiti API to deploy process with `tenantId`.

I want to know if there is a way to do that using Activiti Explorer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No - Explorer is not multi-tenant aware". Joram Barrez, Activiti Core Developer